# How to add empty spaces into MD markdown readme on GitHub?

Tags: github, formatting, markdown

I'm struggling to add empty spaces before the string starts to make [my GitHub `README.md`](http://github.com/noduslabs/8os/) looks something like this:

[image]

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

I tried adding `<br />` tag to fix the new string start, now it works, but I don't understand how to add spaces before the string starts without changing everything to `&nbsp;`. Maybe there's a more elegant way to format it?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Instead of using HTML entities like `&nbsp;` and `&emsp;` (as others have suggested), you can use the Unicode em space (8195 in UTF-8) directly.  Try copy-pasting the following into your `README.md`.  The spaces at the start of the lines are em spaces.

```
The action of every agent <br />
  into the world <br />
starts <br />
  from their physical selves. <br />
```

Comment: There's also the [en space](https://codepoints.net/U+2002?lang=en) which is half the width of the em space. There's a 'Copy to Clipboard' button to the right, or copy this: ' '

Answer (score 110):

You can use `<pre>` to display all spaces & blanks you have typed. E.g.:

```
<pre>
hello, this is
   just an     example
....
</pre>
```

Comment: But then bold disappears... eg. `<pre> **lalala** </pre>`

Comment: @TonyLucas, not with this solution... That I remember.

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is messing with the design. It changes the background color to light gray and adds a horizontal scrollbar. Not really what I was looking for...

Comment: this  tag  will disappear any internal used HTML tag

Answer (score 87):

Markdown really changes everything to html and html collapses spaces so you really can't do anything about it. You have to use the `&nbsp;` for it. A funny example here that I'm writing in markdown and I'll use couple of          here.

Above there are some `&nbsp;` without backticks

Comment: You can alternate regular spaces with non-breaking spaces (every other one) to save some typing. For example, the following gives you 4 spaces: ``   &nbsp; &nbsp;``

Answer (score 66):

I'm surprised no one mentioned the HTML entities **`&ensp;`** and **`&emsp;`** which produce horizontal white space equivalent to the characters **n** and **m**, respectively. If you want to accumulate horizontal white space quickly, those are more efficient than **`&nbsp;`**.

1. no space
2. `&nbsp;`
3. `&ensp;`
4. `&emsp;`

Along with `<space>` and `&thinsp;`, these are the five entities HTML provides for horizontal white space.

Note that except for `&nbsp;`, all entities allow breaking. Whatever text surrounds them will wrap to a new line if it would otherwise extend beyond the container boundary. With `&nbsp;` it would wrap to a new line as a block even if the text before `&nbsp;` could fit on the previous line.

Depending on your use case, that may be desired or undesired. For me, unless I'm dealing with things like names (John`&nbsp;`Doe), addresses or references (see eq.`&nbsp;`5), breaking as a block is usually undesired.

Answer (score 44):

After different tries, I end up to a solution since most markdown interpreter support *Math environment*. 
The following adds one white space :

```
$~$
```

And here ten:

```
$~~~~~~~~~~~$
```

Comment: I love this solution, much more readable than HTML spacers, and it remains within the Markdown syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, $~$ does not work in GitHub. But  &nbsp;  works fine.

Comment: this is the best solution in my eyes if your markdown editor supports it

Comment: Works flawlessly for streamlit 1.3.1

Answer (score 35):

**Markdown** gets converted into **HTML**/**XHMTL**.

> **John Gruber** created the **Markdown language** in 2004 in collaboration with Aaron Swartz on the syntax, with the goal of enabling people to write using an easy-to-read, easy-to-write plain text format, and optionally convert it to structurally valid **HTML** (or **XHTML**).

**HTML** is completely based on using `&nbsp;` for adding extra spaces if it doesn't externally define/use **JavaScript** or **CSS** for elements.

> **Markdown** is a lightweight markup language with plain text formatting syntax. It is designed so that it can be converted to **HTML** and many other formats using a tool by the same name.

---

If you want to use »

1. only one space » either use `&nbsp;` or just hit `Spacebar` (2nd one is good choice in this case)
2. more than one space » use `&nbsp;`+<kbd>space</kbd> (for 2 consecutive spaces)

---

eg. If you want to add 10 spaces contiguously then you should use

`&nbsp;`      `&nbsp;`      `&nbsp;`      `&nbsp;`      `&nbsp;`

> `&nbsp;`<kbd>space</kbd>`&nbsp;`<kbd>space</kbd>`&nbsp;`<kbd>space</kbd>`&nbsp;`<kbd>space</kbd>`&nbsp;`<kbd>space</kbd>

instead of using 10 `&nbsp;` one after one as the below one

> `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

---

For more details check

1. [Adding multiple spaces between text in Markdown](https://steemit.com/markdown/@jamesanto/how-to-add-multiple-spaces-between-texts-in-markdown),
2. [How to create extra space in HTML or web page](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001662.htm).

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can use a **code block** to render the code **literally**. Just surround your text with triple backticks ```. It will look like this:

`2018-07-20 Wrote this answer
           Can format it without &nbsp;
    Also don't need <br /> for new line`

Note that using `<pre>` and `<code>` you get slightly different behaviour: `&nbsp` and `<br />` will be parsed rather than inserted literally.

`<pre>:`

```
2018-07-20 Wrote this answer
           Can format it without  
    Also don't need 
 for new line
```

`<code>:`

`2018-07-20 Wrote this answer
           Can format it without  
    Also don't need 
 for new line`

Comment: Your answer could be an edit to this answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645390/5250746 by @terry.qiao There is no actual difference between these two answers.

Comment: I didn't know <pre> is used for a code block so I hadn't paid attention. There seem to be difference, however, w.r.t. interpreting embedded tags. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use spaces from the known list:

```
&#8202; &hairsp;
'6-per-em space' &#8198;
'narrow no-break space' &#8239;
'thin space' &#8201; &thinsp;
'4-per-em space' &#8197; &emsp14;
'no breaking space' &#160; &nbsp;
'punctuation space' &#8200; &puncsp;
'3-per-em space' &#8196; &emsp13;
'en space' &#8194; &ensp;
'figure space' &#8199; &numsp;
'em space' &#8195; &emsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried so many methods on Github markdown.

Only starting the line with </br> with a normal empty line underneath works for me.
(so two line in total; one just </br> and one is empty)

One line of </br> will do the line break. The reason for the empty line underneath is that it won't mess up the formats of the content coming up.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33074478)

Answer (score 0):

Since Html is valid in markdown ,you can do like 
 this for example if you want to preserve your design:

```
### Data Description
 <pre>
   - <strong>children</strong>             : number of children in the family
   - <strong>days_employed</strong>        : total work experience in days
   - <strong>dob_years</strong>            : client's age in years
</pre>
```

#### Data Description

- **children**             : number of children in the family 
- **days_employed**        : total work experience in days 
- **dob_years**            : client's age in years