# How can I add extra spaces to inline codes (R Markdown)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to add extra spaces to inline code spans. How can I manage it?

[image: Pic]

`1    +                2` didn't work. `<br></br>` didn't work. `&emsp;` and `&nbsp;` didn't work.

Info: I'm knitting to HTML. Theme is `rmdformats::downcute`.

Comment: You could try directly using em space, copy paste this character: ' '. See also the accepted answer for this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810511/how-to-add-empty-spaces-into-md-markdown-readme-on-github

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add empty spaces into MD markdown readme on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810511/how-to-add-empty-spaces-into-md-markdown-readme-on-github)

Comment: It doesn't. I'm trying to add extra spaces to inline code spans (`     `).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO this is related to `rmdformats::downcute`, i.e. the spaces are preserved when I render using the default `html_document`. But one option would be to add your spaces using `&nbsp;` and adding your inline code using a `code` tag:

```
---
title: 'Test'
output: rmdformats::downcute
---

`1 + 2` and <code>1 + &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2</code> both are 3.
```

[image]